# How to remove several columns and the field separators at once in AWK?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a big file with several thousands of columns. I want to delete some specific columns and the field separators at once with AWK in Bash.

I can delete one column at a time with this oneliner (column 3 will be deleted and its corresponding field separator):

```
awk -vkf=3 -vFS="\t" -vOFS="\t" '{for(i=kf; i<NF;i++){ $i=$(i+1);}; NF--; print}' < Big_File
```

However, I want to delete several columns at once... Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: No, it's not. Here you choose specific columns, not columns within a interval...

Comment: I beg to differ. In both questions mentioned above answers for removing both ranges and lists of columns occur.

Comment: For AWK, I could not really find it...

Comment: I have been too hasty in my voting. Indeed both questions have answers for how to do this with `cut`, but not with `awk`. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an implementation of Kamil's idea:

```
awk -v remove="3,8,5" '
  BEGIN {
    OFS=FS="\t"
    split(remove,a,",")
    for (i in a) b[a[i]]=1
  }                                                          
  {
    j=1
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
      if (!(i in b)) { 
        $j=$i
        ++j
      }
    }
    NF=j-1
    print
  }
'
```

Comment: Thank you, however that script change the field separators, I want to keep using "tab" as separator, any idea?

Comment: Not putting a space between -v and the variable assignments makes your solution unnecessarily gawk-specific. Also, if you're going to set FS and OFS to the same value it's more concise to just use FS=OFS="\t" in the BEGIN section.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass list of columns to be deleted from shell to `awk` like this:

```
awk -vkf="3,5,11" ...
```

then in the `awk` programm parse it into array:

```
split(kf,kf_array,",")
```

and then go thru all the colums and test if each particular column is in the kf_array and possibly skip it

Other possibility is to call your oneliner several times :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `cut` instead of `awk`, this one is easier with `cut`:

e.g. this obtains columns 1,3, and from 50 on from file:

`cut -f1,3,50- file`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
awk -F'\t' -v remove='3|8|5' '
{
   rec=ofs=""
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      if (i !~ "^(" remove ")$" ) {
         rec = rec ofs $i
         ofs = FS
      }
   }
   print rec
}
' file
```